# Remove a box shadow (SASS + Compass)

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am removing the box shadow CSS with my media query:

```
.myelements {
    @include box-shadow(2px 2px 3px #000);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .myelements {
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}
```

Instead of re-defining the css as `none` and having to use all the vendor prefixes I was wondering if there was more elegant sassier way? I am using SASS and Compass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct value is `none`:

```
.myelements {
    @include box-shadow(2px 2px 3px #000);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .myelements {
        @include box-shadow(none);
    }
}
```

However, you should avoid repeatedly setting/unsetting properties whenever possible to get a smaller CSS file:

```
.myelements {
    // nothing
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .myelements {
        @include box-shadow(2px 2px 3px #000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it transparent:

```
.myelements {
    @include box-shadow(2px 2px 3px #000);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    @include box-shadow(0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
```

Comment: Is that the most elegant way? I thought there may of been a `@include box-shadow(none);` or something.